# Reading and displaying French characters in WebBrowser (C#)

Tags: c#, encoding, webbrowser-control

I'm using Visual Studio Community in C# (.Net 2.0).
I'm having problems reading data on a web page loaded in a WebBrowser control and then displaying it in a WebBrowser control.
The web page uses the "iso-8859-1" character set.
I've tried using "Document.Encoding" as you can see by the commented lines in the following code, but it keeps displaying these black losanges with a white question mark in it instead of French characters.
I know, this program does nothing useful, it's just an exemple to show you the problem.
What am I doing wrong?
I spent three days looking for a solution.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string myquery = "";
        string html = "";
        string results = "";
        int start;
        int end;
        //string encodage = "";

        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        myquery = "http://citoyens.soquij.qc.ca/index.php";
        webBrowser1.Navigate(myquery);
        do {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
        //encodage = webBrowser1.Document.Encoding;
        //MessageBox.Show(encodage);
        html = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        start = html.IndexOf("a class=\"petit_logo\"");
        start = html.IndexOf(">", start);
        end = html.IndexOf("<", start);
        results += html.Substring(start, end - start);
        //webBrowser1.Document.Encoding = encodage;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = results;
        //MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.Encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is documentstream is not properly encoded with required encoding format. You might have to use document.write after the document is encoded in required encoding format as shown below.

```
 WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        string myquery = "";
        string html = "";
        string results = "";
        int start;
        int end;
        //string encodage = "";

        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        myquery = "http://citoyens.soquij.qc.ca/index.php";
        webBrowser1.Navigate(myquery);
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);

        // For UTF-8 encoding. 
        //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webBrowser1.DocumentStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        //string source = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //string encodage = webBrowser1.Document.Encoding;
        //MessageBox.Show(encodage);


        // Similarly, for "iso-8859-1" character set encoding.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webBrowser1.DocumentStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser1.Document.Encoding)))
        {
            string source = sr.ReadToEnd();
            webBrowser1.Document.Write(source);
        }

        html = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        start = html.IndexOf("a class=\"petit_logo\"");
        start = html.IndexOf(">", start);
        end = html.IndexOf("<", start);
        results += html.Substring(start, end - start);
        //webBrowser1.Document.Encoding = encodage;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = results; //use Document.write(text) method.
```

Comment: Thanks Yugendhar, that seems to work, but I don't understand why. The webBrowser control was loaded using Navigate, read using DocumentText and written to, still using DocumentText. Now The webBrowser is loaded using Navigate, I read it using a StreamReader, I write back to it using Document.write, and then I read it again using DocumentText, and write to it once more using DocumentText? Is all that going back and forth a way to bypass a flaw in the webBrowser control? I wish I understood before I move ahead. Could you explain it to me a bit more? Thanks again, you're the best...

Comment: In the first case, DocumentText cannot be overwritten directly and will not be reflecting even though it seems like you are assigning encoded text. In the second case, we are using document.write() method to overwrite the default text with encoded text.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. In the first case, it seemed I was overwriting the content of the control, but without proper encoding. In the second case, it seems to me that I am reading, writing, then reading and writing again. Oh well, the important thing is it works. Perhaps I'll understand as I get better. Thanks again...